# How to solve the following matrix equation?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

$$A+BX^{-1}B=X$$

where $A$ is a square matrix and Hermitian, $B=B^T$ and $B$ has real entries. I want to find the square matrix $X$. If an analytic solution does not exist, a numerical solution will also suffice. Furthermore, can we find the properties of X from this equation? I encountered this equation trying to equate two exponentials:
$$\exp\left[z^T\left(A+BX^{-1}B\right)z\right]=\exp\left(z^TXz\right)$$

where $z$ is a real column matrix.

Comment: Can you please describe where this equation comes from? Maybe it's simpler to think in the original terms.

Comment: The equation is not linear in $X$. Think of the 1-dimensional case.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Sylvester equation is linear in $X$, however this equation is not. Actually it seems to be no analytical solution for this in general case, because it is a system of polynomial equations in general, which may have a power bigger than 4.

Comment: @spiridon_the_sun_rotator Indeed, I am expecting a system of polynomial equations of any degree $n>0$. However, I am a little worried if this equation is consistent, that the left side can actually be equal to the right.

Comment: If $z$ is fixed, you don't need $A+BX^{-1}B=X$. All you need is $z^T(A+BX^{-1}B)z=z^TXz+2k\pi i$ for some integer $k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $B$ happens to be invertible, you may put $C=AB^{-1},\,Y=XB^{-1}$ and rewrite the equation as $C+Y^{-1}=Y$. Hence every solution $Y$ must commute with $C$ and $Y^2-CY-I=0$. It follows that
$$
Y=\frac{C+\sqrt{C^2+4I}}{2}
$$
where $\sqrt{C^2+4I}$ some matrix square root of $C^2+4I$. If you can find one such square root that commutes with $C$ and makes $Y$ invertible, then $X=YB$ is indeed a solution to the original equation. In particular, if $C$ is a diagonalisable matrix with a real spectrum, you may simply pick the "natural" square root $PD^{1/2}P^{-1}$, where $C^2+4I=PDP^{-1}$ is an eigendecomposition and $D^{1/2}$ is the entrywise square root of $D$.

**Remark.** There is actually no need to solve the matrix equation $A+BX^{-1}B=X$, because it suffices to solve
$$
z^T\left(A+BX^{-1}B\right)z=z^TXz.\tag{1}
$$
If $z^TAz\ne0$ or $Bz\ne0$, the quadratic equation $\|z\|^2x^2-(z^TAz)x-\|Bz\|^2=0$ has a nonzero root $x=\frac12\left(z^TAz+\sqrt{(z^TAz)^2+4\|z\|^2\|Bz\|^2}\right)$. Hence we may take $X=xI$.

If $z^TAz=0$ and $Bz=0$ but $z\in\mathbb R^n$ is nonzero, extend $\{z\}$ to an orthogonal basis $\{z,u,v_3,v_4,\ldots,v_n\}$ of $\mathbb R^n$. Let $Y=\pmatrix{u+z&u-z&v_3&\cdots&v_n}$. Then $X=YY^T$ is an invertible matrix that solves $(1)$.

If $z=0$, any invertible $X$ will solve $(1)$.

Comment: I have to do a gaussian integral on the right-hand side so z cannot be fixed, I missed that before. However, to do a gaussian integral we need to know if X is positive definite or not, i.e. $\Re(z^TXz)>0$ Is there any way to infer that X is positive definite?

Comment: @Reshad If $B$ is positive definite, there is a positive definition solution in the form of the $Y$ above, with $C$ replaced by $B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2}$. Not sure about the other cases.

Comment: $B$ is indeed symmetric and positive definite. Are you saying that $Y$ will then be positive definite or $X$?

Comment: @Reshad Both. When $B$ is positive definite, put $C=B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2}$ and $Y=B^{-1/2}XB^{-1/2}$. The equation then reduces to $Y^2-CY-I=0$ and it has a positive definite solution $Y=\frac12(C+\sqrt{C^2+4I})$. Hence $X=B^{1/2}YB^{1/2}$ is also positive definite.